# How to iterate over any array to return the value "true" if any elements are true

Tags: javascript

This question is regarding JavaScript.
If the input is any of the following array "hello, hi, yo, or hey", I want the value to return true, but it is only returning false.

I've tried multiple methods like toString(), includes(), etc.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var arr1 = [/hello/i, /\bhi/i, /\bhey/i, /\byo\s/i];
  var b = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    var greeting1 = arr1[i].test(b);
    greeting1.toString()
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting1
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1">
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I want the value to return true.

Comment: You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Because you are not breaking loop once match found. If you break from loop when match found then you will get correct output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.some()` to check if at least one of the regular expressions match. I've modified a little bit your code just to give you an example:

```js
function myFunction(value) {
    var arr1 = [/hello/i, /\bhi/i, /\bhey/i, /\byo\s/i];
    console.log(arr1.some(a => a.test(value)));        
}

myFunction('hello');
```

The problem in your code is that you are overriding the text with the result of each iteration of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to `break` the loop once a regular expression `test()` returns `true`:

```js
function myFunction()
{
    var arr1 = [/hello/i, /\bhi/i, /\bhey/i, /\byo\s/i];
    var b = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var res = false;

    for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
    {
        res = arr1[i].test(b);

        if (res)
            break;
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1">
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

However, you can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to simplify your code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var arr1 = [/hello/i, /\bhi/i, /\bhey/i, /\byo\s/i];
  var b = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr1.some(regexp => regexp.test(b));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1">
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Comment: @AnthonyAlexander You are welcome, take into consideration to accept one of the answers the people made for you, obviously, when you have some time.